# Java Enum: Encapsulation and runtime initialization

Tags: java, enums

I have a funny question on the way home

I have an Enum

```
public enum Gender{

    Yes(Constants.male()), female(Constants.female());

    private final String value;

    private Gender(String option){
          value = option;
    }
}
```

.. should I encapsulate value or just declare it as public?

Is there a disadvantage of run-time initializing the value?

Comment: Ha! `Gender.Yes -> male`.

Comment: `Yes` and `female`? The constructor is named `Option` instead of `Gender`?

Comment: sorry should be gender =x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there shouldn't be much difference, the `String` class is immutable. It is recommended however as encapsulation is good practice.

As far as "run-time" init, I am not sure what you mean. Enum's as essentially singleton's so this would be inited when it is class-loaded. This is at runtime, yes, but there are no disadvantages; especially if you do not want to hardcode the values.

**EDIT**

As @GyroGearless points out the field should be declared as `final`, this is best practice even if it isn't `public` as it's a constant set in the constructor.

Comment: Alas, String would be immutable, but not the value field! If made public, it should be declared as "final public"! I'd also prefer to encapsulate the field using a getter to be more consistent with widely accepted best practices.

Comment: Good point - should certainly be `final` if it's `public`.